# Using geography cast as geometry in QGIS No SRID in Airports table. Other table have geom and is 26986

Tags: qgis-3, sql, postgresql

I trying to add a layer into the map in QGIS. It will execute the SQL and show the answer but will not add it to the map. It states there a geometry error. I type cast `geom::geography` it should allow it.

```sql
SELECT name, iso_country, iso_region, ST_Transform(geog::geometry,4326)
FROM ch10.airports
WHERE ST_DWithin(geog, ST_Point(-94.173653,36.067833)::geography, 100000)
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: `ST_Transform` is used to reproject, not cast.  Have you tried just casting (`geog::geometry`), or a cast inside `ST_SetSRID`?

Comment: inside the ST_DWithin with SRID. Where would you suggestion add it?

Comment: `ST_DWithin` requires either `geometry` or `geography`, the first two params of the same type, and if `geometry` with the same SRID. `geography` has an implicit SRID of 4326. The `ST_Transform` serves no purpose.  Please [Edit] the question to provide more information about the contents of the `airports` table (especially what SRID is used).  The exact error should also always be specified.

Comment: You've now highlighted multiple problems in the title, but have not addressed them at all in the question.